# Acceder orden con fecha primera y última cita dada una fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la típica tabla maestro detalle `cita` y `detalles_cita` 
donde `detalles_cita` contiene la `cita_id` y la `fecha` de `cita`.

```
cita
+----+---------+
| id | nombre  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | cita 01 |
|  2 | cita 02 |
|  3 | cita 03 |
|  4 | cita 04 |
+----+---------+

detalles_citas
+-----+---------+------------+
| id  | cita_id |   fecha    |
+-----+---------+------------+
|  1  |      1  | 2019-11-01 |
|  2  |      1  | 2019-11-02 |
|  3  |      1  | 2019-11-03 |
|  4  |      1  | 2019-11-22 |
|  5  |      1  | 2019-11-13 |
|  6  |      1  | 2019-11-06 |
|  7  |      1  | 2019-11-07 |
|  8  |      1  | 2019-11-10 | -> último reg
|  9  |      2  | 2019-11-05 |
| 10  |      2  | NULL       |
| 11  |      2  | NULL       |
| 12  |      2  | 2019-11-21 |
| 13  |      2  | 2019-11-22 | -> último reg
| 14  |      2  | NULL       |
| 15  |      2  | NULL       |
| 16  |      2  | 2019-11-25 | 
| 17  |      3  | 2019-11-05 |
| 18  |      3  | 2019-11-07 |
| 19  |      3  | 2019-11-22 |
| 20  |      3  | 2019-11-12 | -> último reg
+-----+---------+------------+
```

Busco obtener dada una fecha exacta la cita, fecha_buscada y ultimo_reg_fecha_cita
donde `ultimo_reg_fecha_cita` es la última fecha registro con fecha de esa cita

Ejemplo de lo que deberia sacar para el dia 2019-11-22

```
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+
|  cita  | fecha_buscada | ultimo_reg_fecha_cita |
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+
| cita01 | 2019-11-22    | 2019-11-10            |
| cita02 | 2019-11-22    | 2019-11-22            |
| cita03 | 2019-11-22    | 2019-11-12            |
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Otro ejemplo de lo que deberia sacar para el dia 2019-11-06

```
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+
|  cita  | fecha_buscada | ultimo_reg_fecha_cita |
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+
| cita01 | 2019-11-06    | 2019-11-10            |
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: En el segundo ejemplo la fecha `2019-11-06` es la fecha exacta que solo tiene `cita01`, y `ultimo_reg_fecha_cita` es el último registro de fecha que tiene `cita01` -> `2019-11-10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor sería primero unir las tablas y para obtener la última fecha realizar una subconsulta ordenando por la columna `id`, entiendo que esa columna tiene un autoincrementable, asi que algo así debería funcionar:

```
SELECT c.nombre AS cita,
        dc.fecha AS fecha_buscada,
        (SELECT TOP 1 fecha
        FROM detalles_cita
        WHERE cita_id = c.id AND fecha IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY id DESC) AS ultimo_reg_fecha_cita
FROM cita c
INNER JOIN detalles_cita dc ON c.id = dc.cita_id
WHERE dc.fecha = @tufechaabuscar
```

No entiendo tu query, ahí tienes varias tablas que no has mencionado, lo que te he pasado es solo para tu pregunta con respecto a las dos tablas que comentas.

Comment: Este ejemplo es una simplificación de mi problema real y la query que he puesto es la final que estaba haciendo la he quitado para que no genere confusión.